# How to Pass Element ID's through SetTimeout Functions in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I want to pass id1, id2 and id3 through the function below. This works just fine:

```
function doSomething(id1,id2,id3) {
    $(id1).fadeIn('slow',.25);
    $(id1).fadeIn('slow',.25);
    $(id1).fadeIn('slow',.25);
};
```

But this does not work:

```
function doSomething(id1,id2,id3) {
    setTimeout( " $(id1).fadeIn('slow',.25) ", 300);
    setTimeout( " $(id1).fadeIn('slow',.25) ", 300);
    setTimeout( " $(id1).fadeIn('slow',.25) ", 300);
};
```

How do I get the second one to work? My thought is I need some punctuation around the id's. Or perhaps I can set a variable for the function within the setTimeout brackets. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's bad practice to get `setTimeout()` to evaluate a string. Instead, use an anonymous function:

```
function doSomething(id1, id2, id3) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(id1).fadeIn('slow', 0.25);
        $(id2).fadeIn('slow', 0.25);
        $(id1).fadeIn('slow', 0.25);
    }, 300);
};
```

Note that I've put all your `fadeIn()`s into one `setTimeout()`; it does the same thing as all your timeouts will trigger at the same time (300ms). If you IDs are strings, you could do this too:

```
function doSomething(id1, id2, id3) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(id1 + ', ' + id2 + ', ' + id3).fadeIn('slow', 0.25);
    }, 300);
};
```

Although it's a little messy, but [`$.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) might do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

setTimeout accepts a function callback and a timeout. By wrapping your function call in quotes, you're passing it a string. Try this:

```
function doSomething(id1,id2,id3) {
    setTimeout( function() { 
       $(id1).fadeIn('slow',.25);
       $(id2).fadeIn('slow',.25);
       $(id3).fadeIn('slow',.25); 
    }, 300);
};
```

**EDIT**:
As @nnnnnn pointed out, a string can be passed but it is a bad [idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout). Essentially, when you pass in a string it is called with the privileges of the caller and thus will not have access to the scope variables within "doSomething" but a completely different scope.

Comment: Passing a string to `setTimeout` isn't inherently wrong - it is certainly valid syntax. The problem with the string syntax is the code in the string won't run in the right scope to make use of the local `id1` and other parameters, something that your code fixes.